# Column value as a `REGEXP` pattern in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Is is possible to use column value as a `REGEXP` pattern in SQLAlchemy?

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
column int(200) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With two sample rows:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, column)
VALUES
(1, '^S[[:digit:]]{10}$'),
(2, '^M[[:digit:]]{8}$');
```

In mysql one can do:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE 'S1803020001' REGEXP my_table.column;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

I am looking for a way to do it in SQLAlchemy.

That's how I use literal `regexp` with my model:

```
MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.column.op('regexp')(r'pattern'))
```

but this time I am looking for a way to swap 'pattern' and 'MyTable.column'.

I am aware it might not be supported due to various underlying database backends, as not all backends support non-literal `regexp` patterns. Nonetheless I am curious if and how can it be achieved.

Comment: `literal('foo').op('regexp')(MyTable.column)`, probably.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks, that worked great! Consider posting an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`literal()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal) simply reverse the operation:

```
literal('foo').op('regexp')(MyTable.column)
```